# Recover from failed INSERT query without additional db interrogations

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling

I have to perform some INSERT upon creating users in a web application.
In the case that the query fails I want to know if it did because of a duplicate entry for the PRIMARY or for one of the other two indexes.
I'd like to avoid testing for each one with additional queries because I need to create around a half hundred users at a time, and it may take too long.

I searched the PHP manual looking for MYSQLI's error handling, but I only found $errno (code 1062 in my case) and $sqlstate (code 25000);
This info does not tell me which one of the indexes is the culprit.

Since the $error string reports the value that caused the failure (for example it says "Duplicate entry 'someValue' for key 'indexName_UNIQUE'") I was wondering if I can get 'someValue' somehow and therefore identify the culprit.
Running a strpos() on the string message doesn't look like good practice.

We are using MariaDB.

Comment: _Running a strpos() on the string message doesn't look like good practice._ But its your only choice.

Comment: You can use a regular expression rather than `strpos()`. Use the regexp `/for key '(.*?)'/`

Comment: I have to admit I have never used it, but did you try looking at [mysqli::$error_list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error-list.php)